RVIZ shows completely incorrect joint limits
I am using the franka fr3 URDF: https://pastebin.com/Bg7MTmnk
I control the joints visualized in RVIZ with the following:
ros2 run joint_state_publisher_gui joint_state_publisher_gui

however the joint limits in rviz GUI are completely wrong, as seen below. What gives?


You might want to consider resizing the UI so that the numbers are display fully...
The numbers you see correspond to the last 2 decimal places...
example:
fr3_joint1
upper="2.7437"
fr3_joint2
upper="1.7837"
fr3_joint3
upper="2.9007"
